# How to disable "Subscription Notification" emails when subscribing to a list

Tags: exm

When users subscribe to a list via `ClientApi.UpdateSubscriptions` (or using a built in control, presumably) a confirmation email is sent to them even if the `confirmSubscription` parameter is false.

The email has the subject "Subscription Notification" and the body "You have successfully subscribed to this email group."

Is there a way to disable this email from being sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr - Delete `[Manager Root]/Messages/Service Messages/Self-Service Subscription/Subscription Notification` and the emails will stop sending.

There no is no explicit option to disable the email, but if the confirmation email cannot be found it will simply be skipped and won't throw an error.

The confirmation email is located via a relative path from the `Messages` folder inside the Manager Root (eg. "Email Campaign"). The path comes from the `StandardMessages.SubscriptionNotification` setting, which has a default value of "Service Messages/Self-Service Subscription/Subscription Notification".

NB. The `confirmSubscription` parameter of `ClientApi.UpdateSubscriptions` relates to sending the user an email that request that *they* confirm the subscription before actually being added to the list. Its path is defined via the `StandardMessages.SubscriptionConfirmation` setting, but there's no need to delete that item if you set `confirmSubscription` to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to set the value of the following settings (/App_Config/Include/EmailExperience/Sitecore.EmailExperience.ContentManagement.config):

```
<setting name="StandardMessages.UnsubscribeNotification" value="Service Messages/Self-Service Subscription/Unsubscribe Notification" />
<setting name="StandardMessages.UnsubscribeFromAllNotification" value="Service Messages/Self-Service Subscription/Unsubscribe From All Notification" />
```

in the following way:

```
 <setting name="StandardMessages.UnsubscribeNotification" value="" />
 <setting name="StandardMessages.UnsubscribeFromAllNotification" value="" />
```

This should prevent sending of the notification mails for all the "unsubscribed" users.
For more details regarding the settings please see the article:
https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/setting_up_exm/the_exm_configuration_settings

Comment: Technically this code path would involve a bit more work. The way the code is written, would think the "messages" folder _is_ the message a d attempt to send it. Only further down the chain would it exit, and may even involve a caught exception. Whereas if the confirmation item resolves to null it's simply skipped.